# polyglossia conflicts with \.{S} but not \.{R}

Tags: polyglossia, option-clash

Loading Polyglossia somehow disables the command `\.{S}` but doesn't effect others, like `\.{R}` and `\.{G}`. This is odd, can anyone think of why this is happening and what to do to get `\.{S}` to work again? I am building the document using XeLatex.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}    % This will prevent \.{S} from working.

\begin{document}
\.{S}
\.{R}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see the same with xelatex (texlive 2017) whether or not you load those packages (it's recommended not to use xlxtra) you get a dot over both letters but the dot over the S is too low, which looks like an issue with latin modern font in use.

Comment: I see, I removed xltxtra and fontspec, because it appears I don't even need them for my document.

If I remove all packages and run with XeLatex, I do get a proper result. The S is appropriately placed. MWE: `\documentclass{book}



\begin{document}

\.{S}
\.{R}
 
\end{document}`

Comment: The default Latin Modern font has a bug that prevents the dot over S to be placed correctly.

Comment: what date is your latex? With the current version the dot over the s is lower than the S but old latex without fontspec would give you 7 bit computer modern which would fix that problem but there are then no benefits to using xelatex.

Comment: Ah, I use MikTex, and I don't know how to check what version I'm using but I found the updates installer, and now the problem is as you describe: The dot is too low... interesting... and annoying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `polyglossia` package is not really involved and just `fontspec` is sufficient to reproduce the issue (it is loaded by `polyglossia`).

The Latin Modern font used by default seem to have a bug with the placement of the combining dot over S.

A simple workaround might be

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}    

\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\.}{TU}{S}{\accent"02D9 S}

\begin{document}

\.{S}
\.{R}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe better:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\.}{TU}{S}{\mydottedS}
\newcommand{\mydottedS}{%
  \leavevmode\vbox{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr\char"02D9\cr\noalign{\kern-1.15ex}S\cr}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\.{S}
\.{R}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Other fonts don't suffer from the problem. For instance CMU Serif:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\begin{document}

\.{S}
\.{R}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sure this all works, but I can't get it to work because updating miktex after reading the above comments now fontspec is giving me the error message: `Undefined control sequence. \sys_if_engine_luatex:T`. I'll mark the answer after I can check that your two fixes work on my computer as well.

Comment: On a separate note, I'll just use it blindly for now, but I have no idea how your solutions work/what they do. Is there a book or other resource that systematically teaches one to understand what you did? Or is this not a sensible way to approach learning the inner workings of LaTeX?

Comment: @MaanDoabeDa You seem to need a thorough update of your TeX system.

Comment: Indeed, I had never done that before.